# NVM in nodejs returns "no shasum" error

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I installed NVM on my system and tried to install a newer version of nodejs by the following commands:

```
nvm install v0.8.23
```

and

```
nvm install 0.8.23
```

But I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/which: no shasum in ($PATH)
######################################################################## 100.0%
Checksums do not match.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Additional options while compiling: 
nvm: install N/A failed!
```

and then nothing happens. How can I fix this problem?!

Update-1_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

I tried changing the permission and creating an alias but they didn't effect anything.
I made a symlink shasum -> sha1sum and the output changed (but still I'm not having ):

```
######################################################################## 100.0%
Checksums do not match.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Additional options while compiling: 
nvm: install N/A failed!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Mac OS X, you can try this:

```
sudo chmod 555 /usr/bin/shasum
nvm install ...
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, you need to install `shasum` (perhaps using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)).

If you're on Linux, use your distro's package manager to install it.

Comment: Is `sha1sum` findable in your `$PATH`? In other words, what happens if you run `sha1sum` on the command line?

Comment: yes, I have /usr/bin/sha1sum and my $PATH contains /usr/bin ! The permission is 755!

Comment: do you use `zsh` by any chance?

Comment: actually I have no idea what the 'zsh' is! if it's a shell or a shell command, I don't have it

Comment: Okay, if you don't know what it is you're probably not using it :) But I don't know what's causing `nvm` not being able to find `sha1sum`. Perhaps it works when you copy `/usr/bin/sha1sum` to `/usr/bin/shasum` (or symlink it).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29225/discussion-between-emab-and-robertklep)

Comment: Sorry about that, had to step out for a bit. Does your update mean that you're not getting the error message about `shasum` not being found anymore?

Comment: yes, in fact not I get the error about checksum not maching (you can read the whole error in the post)

Comment: Are you using a proxy that might be blocking downloads or modifying them or anything like that? I can reproduce the problem when I try to install a non-existing version, like `0.8.24`, but `0.8.23` works just fine for me (Mac OS X).

Comment: No, yesterday I did it on my own computer, ad now it doesn't work with that one. can you tell me which packages it usually tries to get?

Comment: when I try 'wget "http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.23/node-v0.8.23.tar.gz"' I get: "ERROR 404: Not Found."

Comment: Thanks robert, the problem was something like that.